# Dynamic width DIV at center of parent

Tags: html, css, position

In the code below, `.hover-tooltip` is a div with width set to `max-content`. I want to position this div at the center of parent div `.hover-wrap` irrespective of its width because content inside `.hover-tooltip` is dynamic. I tried with `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: calc(50% - 10px)` but with no luck.

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.hover-wrap', function(){
  $(this).find('.hover-tooltip').show();
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.hover-wrap', function(){
  $(this).find('.hover-tooltip').hide();
});
```

```css
table{
margin-top: 100px;
}

.hover-wrap{
position: relative;
padding: 5px;
background: #eee;
}

.hover-div{
width: 65px;
height: 65px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
cursor: pointer;
}

.hover-tooltip{
position: absolute;
bottom: calc(100% + 10px);
background: #555;
color: #fff;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
width: max-content;
display: none;
margin: auto;
}

.hover-tooltip:before{
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 100%;
margin-left: -5px;
border-top: 10px solid #555;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="hover-wrap">
      <div class="hover-div">1</div>
      <div class="hover-tooltip">This is tooltip</div>
    </td>
    <td class="hover-wrap">
      <div class="hover-div">1</div>
      <div class="hover-tooltip">Small</div>
    </td>
    <td class="hover-wrap">
      <div class="hover-div">1</div>
      <div class="hover-tooltip">This is a long tooltip</div>
    </td>
    <td class="hover-wrap">
      <div class="hover-div">1</div>
      <div class="hover-tooltip">This is a very very very long tooltip</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to center a `div` inside another `div` ? Can you try `{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
.hover-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(100% + 0px);
    background: #555;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: max-content;
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe, I forgot to use transform.